# Not understanding the difference between relationships UML

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, class-diagram

Here I have this class diagram:

[image]

Here are the things that I don't understand:

1. Why is `Order` - `OrderDetail` an aggregation? Shouldn't it just be an association, since it will have a `List<OrderDetail>` like:

```
public Order{
    public DateTime date;
    public Status status;
    public List<OrderDetail> orderDetails;
}
```

2. Why is `OrderDetail` - `Item` a dependency? Shouldn't it be association since it has a reference to that `Item` class?

Reference for the diagram:
http://sslabmcs12.weebly.com/resources1.html

Comment: Rumbaugh, one of the UML coinventor used to say that “aggregation is a modelling placebo” because many think it’s absolutely needed to clarify their meaning whereas it does in all objectivity not add anything that would really be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, a *simple* association would be the right choice. Anyhow, this is a `shared aggregation` which has no defined semantics. See p. 110 of UML 2.5:

> Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

So you best ask the diagram author about his intentions.

2. It's not a dependency but an association. A dependency would be rendered with a dashed line. The navigability (the arrow right which made you belief it's a dependency) however is of minor use. It indicates that `OrderDetail` can see `Item` but not vice versa. A fact that could better be expressed by using role names only at one side. E.g. placing `item` only on the right hand side and nothing to the left.

What can we learn? UML is about communication!

Comment: Excellent answer to an excellent questions !

Comment: Why do you think a simple association is the right choice? I would say Order-OrderDetail is a composition.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Of course it depends. Given the source (UML diagram) there is only one chance: ask the author. He probably used the 'old definition' which suggests to *not* use a composite aggregation.

Comment: I don't know why I asked the second question, as it was obviously an association. Thanks a lot for the clear answer.